# joomla 4 custom field auto text cleanup

Tags: php, custom-field, joomla-4.x, html

I have this Joomla 4 installed website and I need a custom field(Editor type) for my product specifications which is going to be showing a table.

For example, if I put this code:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

when I save it, it will convert the code to this:

```
<p>CompanyContactCountry</p>
<p>Alfreds Futterkiste<br />Maria Anders<br />Germany</p>
<p>Centro comercial Moctezuma<br />Francisco Chang<br />Mexico</p>
```

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Welcome to JSE, please take our [tour] while you wait for support/feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be an issue with the filter value, either in the field plug-in settings, or in the settings.

The editor field type has four options for filter:

- No
- Raw
- SafeHTML
- Text

Perhaps try setting the filter to "Raw" and see if this still happens.  The default is 'Text' in Joomla 4.

The editor field plug-in settings look like this, see the Filter field:

[image: Field plug-in settings]

The editor field settings look like this, see the Filter field:

[image: Field settings]